# Python: generate a string array based on indexing

Tags: python

I have two arrays defined as:

```
Winter   =   np.array( [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ] ) 
Summer   =   np.array( [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] )
Other    =   np.array( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
```

I have another array of months as:

```
GivenMonths = np.array([ 3, 4,  8,  8, 10,  7])
```

I want to generate a SeasonIdentifier as:

```
SeasonIdentifier = [ 'Other', 'Summer', 'Summer', 'Summer', 'Winter', 'Summer' ]
```

i.e. for each element of GivenMonths I want to find whether it is from Winter or Summer array and store that information in SeasonIdentifier.

Edit:
Made changes to my orig question based on comments below

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What's the problem?

Comment: The `10` is a problem

Comment: why is 1,2,3 present in both winter and other ? so if we find 1,2,3 then we give priority to Other ?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad as it didnt save the update.

Comment: Is this your actual problem or an abstraction? Asking because I can't understand why you use np.array.

Comment: part of grandfathered code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
SeasonIdentifier =  ['Summer' if x in Summer else 'Winter' if x in Winter else 'Other' for x in GivenMonths]
```

Comment: Sorry I was missing the 'Other' array in my post. But your answer is very close. I am going to try it using elif.

Comment: You don't need to use `.tolist()`